# jquery is select selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, first off this isn't to find a value of a select boxes selected option. But its along the lines there of. I have a function I am working on that will check to see if the value selected matches that of the one being compared to from somewhere else, where if the match is found it does one thing if not it does another. However. Due to a recent requirement. The original function breaks cause there is not the probability that the select wont even be touched prior to the need of function.

So Im trying to tell if theres anyway to check to see if the select in question has had anything chosen or not prior to it doing anything else. I'm thinking of the concept of checking for an empty array with length, but I'm not looking to see if the select is empty or not. I need to know if there is a selected value or not so I can act accordingly with that. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm totally not sure if I get you right, but wouldn't this be enough:

```
if( $('option:selected').length ) {
    // at least one option element was selected
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to find if a select has a selected value:

```
var selectedValue = $('#someSelect option:selected').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

There will always be a selected option. Use:

```
var $val = $('select option:selected').val();
```

to capture the value. If no option is selected by the user, the first option will be selected by default. So check against that value. If no value is given to the first option, it will pass back the text of the option. See the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3dwu9/15/).

However, it is important to note that assuming the first option will always be chosen isn't full proof. Some browsers such as FireFox can cache the value of form elements. In order to ensure that the form element acts as expected use the `autocomplete` attribute like so:

```
<select name='something' autocomplete='off'>
```

See: [FireFox Doc on Autocomplete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion)